# Строка как массив символов

Tags: java, строки

Строка — это массив символов. Как в java обратится к букве по индексу? Мой код:

```
String s = "edgw";   // объявляем строку
s = (String) s[-1];  // Заносим в s её последнюю букву
```

Ошибка: `java: array required, but java.lang.String found`

Comment: Попробуй вот так s.toCharArray()[0]

Comment: Java не умеет в индексацию классов, так что даже будь там не "-1", а валидное число, всё равно бы не сработало, к сожалению :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С помощью метода [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

```
String s = "edgw";
char lastChar = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Это работает, но требует создания дополнительной переменной типа char. Можно ли реализовать без неё?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что надо реализовать, то либо `s = String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1))`, либо, лучше, `s = s.substring(s.length() - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Элемента с позицией -1 не существует. Минимальная позиция массива(строки) 0.
То есть например слово СЛОН
С-0
Л-1
О-2
Н-3

Comment: индекс -1 это первый с конца.